# Отслеживание изменения элементов

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, как правильно отследить изменение статуса checked input:radio
и если отмечен, то брать значение соответствующего ему select (платежный метод), с которым он находится в одной строке таблицы.
И наоборот, если произошло изменение select (платёжный метод), то отмечать отмеченным соответствующий input:radio в строке таблицы.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input, select").on("change", function() {
  var $closest = $(this).closest("tr");
  var $input = $closest.find("input");
  var $select = $closest.find("select");
  
  $input[0].checked = true;
  
  alert($input.val() + ": " + $select.val());
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="pay" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  <tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="pay" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Лови пятюню
Можешь еще киви или ЯД дать, на пиво хоть скину)

Comment: @АндрейВоронов ты лучше мой ответ пометь как решение)

Comment: Хорошего дня!
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @lampla нашёл баг небольшой.
Суть заключается в следующем.
Выбираешь селект один раз- отмечается в этой строке input, всё ок.
Если потом выбрать в другой строке- также отмечается, а вот если обратно в первой строке нажать, то остаётся отмеченным прошлый input

Comment: @АндрейВоронов обновил, попробуй.

Comment: @lampla теперь отлично работает. спасибо)